# Regular Express issue - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to replace a text in javascript using a regular expression like following [example of what I am trying to do]:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
  <div id="div1"><a href="#" title="This is Old">This is Old</a></div>
  <script> 
    var message = "Hi";
    var str = document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML;
    var newstr = str.replace(/Old/g, "<div onclick='say(\""+message+"\");'>New</div>");
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = newstr;
    function say(message)
    {
      alert(message);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a sample code of what I am trying to do in a large application. Our script is injected in thrid party html pages, so we dont have control over the html.
If you run this code, you will see that the text appears to be broken and if you just remove the "Old" from the title tag it will work fine. I cannot change the html, so I have to modify the script to handle this.

Is there a way I can put some regular express that can bypass the replacement of the text in case if it occurs in between "<" and ">"?
or some other way to solve this.

I cannot use DOM to do the replacement, as it crashed the page when there were too much text, I am doing full page text replacement.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

EDIT: Changed the code to make it working :)

Comment: @Cem Kalyoncu made the changes to the code, so the message is sent properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be unrelated but, you may need to replace message variable inside the replaced text. Since you declared message variable locally, it will not be available outside.

EDIT:
For your question, you can do that with RegEx but it will be quite hard. If I got time I might work on it a bit.

EDIT 2:
Try this one, it makes sure the Old is not in a tag.

```
>[^><]*(Old)[^<>]*<
```

EDIT 3:
This works file too, starting > is not necassary

```
[^><]*(Old)[^<>]*<
```

EDIT 4:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
  <div id="div1"><a href="#" title="This is Old">This is Old</a></div>
  <script> 
    var message = "Hi";
    var str = document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML;
    var newstr = str.replace(/([^><]*)Old([^<>]*<)/g, "$1<div onclick='say(\""+message+"\");'>New</div>$2");
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = newstr;
    function say(message)
    {
      alert(message);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hope you modified it to be used with replace, I tried it with search. Hang on a sec, Edit 4 is coming :)

Comment: Thank you! seems to work, I will do testing with the live code and see how it goes :)

Comment: Your solution is correct and works in the test environment, but in live environment with lot of text the browser hangs, is there any way of doing with it without too much load on the browser?

Comment: Sadly there not much that can be done for that. But may be you could search to speed up regex. If it is possible, redirect user to a proxy server which will do the replacement. Otherwise you can ask your users to use a fast browser.

Answer (score 1):

Make your replace:

```
str.replace(/(>[^<]*)Old/g, "$1<div onclick='say(\"message\");'>New</div>");
```

Which basically means "Old not in an HTML tag"

Comment: still one issue remaining, <a>Old</a> will not work, instead of + use *

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to assign id to <a> element instead and then run the same replace() on it's innerHTML (which shouldn't contain the tag's title attribute):

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
  <div id="div1"><a id="link" href="#" title="This is Old">This is Old</a></div>
  <script> 
    var message = "Hi";
    var str = document.getElementById("link").innerHTML;
    var newstr = str.replace(/Old/g, "<div onclick='say(\"message\");'>New</div>");
    document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = newstr;
    function say(message)
    {
      alert(message);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont have access to the html, my script is loaded from a seperate js file controlled by me, this script is used by several websites which I dont own or control. :(

Comment: @happyhardik: Sorry, I didn't realize you meant the html in your example as well. I thought you were running inside an iframe and the parent document was messing your script up. What about using document.getElementByTagName("a") instead?

Comment: cant do that, as "a" tag is just an example. It can be "p", "div" headers anything.